# Typescript Record that force all values from string literal unions

Tags: typescript

TypeScript has a built-in type `Record<Key,Value>` that helps to force the object keys and the values. Combining it with enum or string literal union types - and you can force and seek for errors in missing keys.
I'm searching for a type in TypeScript that helps force all Record **values** of string literal unions.
Meaning:

```
type ShortLetterTillC = "A" | "B" | "C";
type LongLetterTillC = "Ai" | "Bi" | "Ci";
type LongLetterTillD = "Ai" | "Bi" | "Ci" | "Di";

// TS2741: Property 'C' is missing in type '{ A: "Ai"; B: "Bi"; }' but required in type 'Record '.
const dictionaryMissingC: Record<ShortLetterTillC, LongLetterTillC> = {
  A: "Ai",
  B: "Bi"
};

// Works - good
const dictionaryC: Record<ShortLetterTillC, LongLetterTillC> = {
  A: "Ai",
  B: "Bi",
  C: "Ci"
};

// Works - I want a type that will make it fail for not having "Di"
const dictionaryD: Record<ShortLetterTillC, LongLetterTillD> = {
  A: "Ai",
  B: "Bi",
  C: "Ci"
};

const dictionaryDThatIWantToForce = {
  A: "Ai",
  B: "Bi",
  C: "Ci",
  D: "Di"
};
```

`dictionaryD` does not error me because the `Record<ShortLetterTillC, LongLetterTillD>` tells TypeScript to have an object with all the keys of `ShortLetterTillC` and for each key - the value can be one of `LongLetterTillD`. While this is good for a lot of use cases - there are some use cases that I want to depend on the values and cover them all like in a dictionary.
Can I have a type that force specifies keys on Record's literal string union values?